# How do I remove \" from string

Tags: c#

```
string value = "\"2\";;\"0_67011297_2013-10-04_2\";\"dfdfd.sfdsf@fdsfsd.PL\";\"fdsf.fdfd@fsdfsdfd.pl\";\"RASP\";;\"2013-10-04\";\"2013-10-04\";\"fdfdfDwfdsfdsór fdsf\";\"Otwarcie fdsf+ wywiad z fdfdfdfds(Wardfdfdszawa)\";\"pkp\";\"MATEfdfdUSZ.fdsfd@fdsfsd.PL\";\"2014-10-01 15:41:20\";\"2014-10-01 15:41:20\";\"utworzony kod delegacji\"";
```

How to remove the `\"` from it?

```
value.Trim( new Char[] { '\\', '\"'});
```

doesnt work.

Help

Comment: how many people should ask this question? -.-

Comment: There is no `\"` in your string it is  `"` char escaped to make it a valid c# string. Try `Console.WriteLine(value)`

Comment: Use the debugger, look at `value`, click on the loupe and you'll see that there is no \

Comment: this question wil be deleted in the nearest future

Answer (score 0):

There is no `\` symbol in the original string. `\` is used to as escape character in your source string.

More reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is used to escape characters (in this case the ").

Why not use ' instead?

```
string value = "'2';;'0_67011297_2013-10-04_2';'dfdfd.sfdsf@fdsfsd.PL';'fdsf.fdfd@fsdfsdfd.pl';'RASP';;'2013-10-04';
```

a.s.o.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
value.Replace(@"\", "")
```

It replaces "\" with an empty string. @ is there so that compiler takes it as it is. If there is no @ in front of "\" it won't work.

Comment: what this does it replaces all occurrences of "\" with an empty string.

Comment: try it in your console: Console.WriteLine(value.Replace(@"\", ""));

Comment: Don't you read comments and other answers before posting an answer. Just try this `Console.WriteLine(value);` **`There is no \ in the string`**